# Rvalue and Move Semantics with Unique Pointer: error for object 0x7ffee5c7b670: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, delete-operator, rvalue-reference, template-classes

I am trying to understand how unique pointers and move semantics. Now, I have created a dummy example below to show what the issue is. My question is, why does this code throw a pointer being freed was not allocated error?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Object
{
public:
    T *values = nullptr;
    int size;
    Object(int size) : size(size)
    {
        values = new T[size];
    }

    ~Object()
    {
        delete[] this->values;
    }

    void myFunc(T *&&new_values)
    {
        cout << "myFunc called!" << endl;
        delete[] this->values;
        values = new_values;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << this->values[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto my_object = new Object<int>(4);
    std::unique_ptr<Object<int>> my_other_object(new Object<int>(4));

    int values[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int my_other_values[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};

    /* This works all fine! */
    my_object->myFunc(std::move(values));
    my_object->print();

    /* This next bit throws pointer being freed was not allocated */
    my_other_object->myFunc(std::move(my_other_values));
    my_other_object->print();
}
```

Comment: You cannot move in an array allocated on the stack into your 'unique ptr' because delete[] ing that array is UB it was never newed. This is effectively like doing: `int x = 4; { auto p = std::unique_ptr<int>(&x); }` which isn't legal either.

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense now. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `std::unique_ptr`. The reason you get the "pointer being freed was not allocated" error is because the shown code is trying to `delete` something that was not `newed`.

```
    delete[] this->values;
    values = new_values;
```

This properly `delete`s the old `values`, but then just blindly sets `values` to point to something that was never `new`ed (the `new_values` that get passed into here are not `new`ed anywhere).

Hence, later, this object's destructor attempts to `delete` what's now in `values`, but it was never `new`ed (it just points to some static array) and you get the runtime error.